# Excluir dados do mysql pelo Jquery

Tags: jquery

Colegas,

tenho um trecho do código onde ao clicar no botão **Adicionar campos**, consigo adicionar e mandar para o banco de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na visualização, estou trazendo os dados da seguinte forma:

```
<?php    
$sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE IDProdutos = '".$idProdutos."';");
    $visualizar = "<table border=\"0\">";

    while($jmTamanhos = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){  
       if($jmTamanhos->Tamanho != ""){
          $visualizar .=  "<tr class='linhas'>
                           <td  style=\"padding: 5px\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"Tamanho[]\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Tamanho\" value='".$jmTamanhos->Tamanho."'></td>
                           <td  style=\"padding: 5px\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"Estoque[]\" class=\"form-control pull-left\" placeholder=\"Estoque\" value='".$jmTamanhos->Estoque."'></td>
                           <td  style=\"padding: 5px\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"removerCampo btn btn-danger\" title=\"Remover linha\"><i class=\"fa fa-minus-square\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> Remover</button></td>
                       </tr>";       
       }
    }
  $visualizar .= "</table>";
    return $visualizar;  
    }
?>
```

Até aqui tudo bem. Ele me retorna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aqui tudo certo, mas como eu faria para que ao clicar em remover, direcionar para a página de exclusão? Tentei com o código abaixo, mas não estou conseguindo. Segue o código:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      function removeCampo() {
        $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
        $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
           if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
           }
        });
      } 
      $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
        novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
        novoCampo.find("input").val("");
        novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
        removeCampo();
      });


     $(".removerCampo").click(function () {
      $.post("excluir-tamanhos.php", $("#excluirCampos").serialize(), function(response) {
          alert('aqui 2');
        $('#success').html(response);
          removeCampo();    
      });
   return false;
  });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: o que exatamente não está dando certo? o arquivo `excluir-tamanhos.php` esta recebendo os dados? Coloque ele ai... (O -1 não fui eu)

Comment: Alterei para  $.post("excluir-tamanhos.php", {IDProdutos: 15, Tamanho: 34}, function(response) { e funcionou. Como faço para passar o valor 15 de produtos e 34 do tamanho? quando coloco id='tamanho' no name='Tamanho[]' para de funcionar.

Comment: Olá @LocalHost .. na verdade nao consigo enviar os dados para o arquivo excluir-tamanhos.php.  O problema nao está no PHP e sim pq nao consigo enviar os dados para essa página.

Comment: Acho que entendi, e acho que seu erro pode estar na forma que voce esta enviando os dados, com o serialize. Você pode criar a mesma função para remover os dados e ainda remover do banco. Ai voce pode pegar os dados que voce vai excluir e enviar, em vez de dar o serialize

Comment: Infelizmente sou leigo no jquery. Você teria algum exemplo para me mostrar?

Comment: Vou ver se consigo colocar um exemplo aqui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo aqui amigo, criei na mesma funçao para deletar e enviar os dados...
Qualquer dúvida comenta ai.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( function () {

            $( ".removerCampo" ).on( "click", function () {
                if ( $( "tr.linhas" ).length > 1 ) {

                    alert( 'aqui 1' );
                    //aqui você esta removendo a linha na qual voce clicou em excluir
                    $( this ).parent().parent().remove();
                    //aqui voce busca dentro dessa linha o input com o nome tamanho
                    var $tamanho = $( this ).parent().parent().find( "input[name=\"Tamanho[]\"]" ).val();
                    //aqui voce busca dentro dessa linha o input com o nome tamanho
                    var $estoque =  $( this ).parent().parent().find( "input[name=\"Estoque[]\"]" ).val();
                        // agora envia para sua pagina de excluir
                        $.post( "excluir-tamanhos.php", {
                            IDProdutos: $estoque,
                            Tamanho: $tamanho
                        }, function ( response ) {
                            alert( 'aqui 2' );
                            $( '#success' ).html( response );
                        } );
                }
                    } );

                $( ".adicionarCampo" ).click( function () {
                    novoCampo = $( "tr.linhas:first" ).clone();
                    novoCampo.find( "input" ).val( "" );
                    novoCampo.insertAfter( "tr.linhas:last" );
                    removeCampo();
                } );

            } );
```

**Vale Lembrar:**

`parent()` : "Pega" o elemento pai

`find()` : "Realiza uma busca", pegando o elemento filho

Comment: Perfeito LocalHost. Funcionou! Obrigado.